# Depedent down menu list in excel or google sheet

Tags: excel

I want to create a drop down menu list that is dependent on the previous selection in excel or googlesheet. 
EX:

```
                  Column A| Column B| Column C
                     A1,     B1,       C1
                     A2,     B2,       C2
```

So if I have a drop down menu list in three columns, I want all of them to be dependent on each other. If i select A1 in column A, B1 and C1 should be selected automatically in Column B and C. If C2 is selected in Column C, A2 and B2 should be selected in Column A and B.

I will have the values that the drop down menu list would read from in a table. I need this ability for comparison products for my company. I checked everywhere with no luck. I'm assuming I'm going to need a macro/script file to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use named range and indirect formula but it a little complex. Can you please provide me your mail id, so that I can give you sample file and procedures to do that. But it is interesting... my e-mail is harun24hr@gmail.com

This is link to do that step by step (Done by me) but it is in Bengali language. You will find download link in this tune.
http://www.techtunes.com.bd/microsoft-excel/tune-id/273609

[image: Screenshot]